# Determine whether the series converge (adding fractions)

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

$$\frac{1}{1 \cdot 3} + \frac{1}{3 \cdot 5} + \frac{1}{5 \cdot 7} + ... $$

Help convert to summation. Not sure what test to use.

Comment: See [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{1}{x(x + 2)} = \frac 1 2\left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x + 2}\right)$$